# Enable Generic Sensor & Generic Sensor Extra Classes chrome flags

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to use the Ambient Light Sensor in my app. How do I enable the chrome flags for electron?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

options.add_argument("--enable-experimental-web-platform-features")

Comment: please explain your answer